# When I save my inputs to a file from memory, then add another packet. Then list them, there seems to be some sort of bug happen [photo included]

Tags: c, memory, structure

So I have a structure

```
struct packet{ // declare structure for packet creation
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;
    int port;
    char data[51];
};
```

When I add some data to this structure it lists fine, if I choose to do so. BUT if i choose to output the entered data within the structure, to a file and then add another packet it starts to mess about with the entries.

The first screenshot is how it should always look after information is entered,

[image: After I have saved then enter another packet]

This screen shot shows what actually happens with data after I have saved and then add another load of information to the structure.
[image: List before I have saved and entered new packet]

This is my add records function

```
 // ADD RECORDS FUNCTION
        struct packet* addRecord(int *rCount, struct packet *records){
        int valid = 0;  //used to indicated valid input
        int length = 0; //used to store the string lengths
        int i = 0;    //used in the for loops
        //char dataTest[51];     //temporary storage of input to be checked before adding to records




    do{
        puts("What is the source of this packet?\nEnter a numerical value between 1 & 1024");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].source) == 1 // do this loop, if source is greater than 1 and less than 1024 the entry is valid
                        && records[*rCount].source >= 1
                        && records[*rCount].source <= 1024)
           {  //if correct insert the record at the index
            valid=1;                                //determined by rCount(the current     record count passed to addRecord
           }
        else{
            valid = 0;                              //else entry is invalid, get any possible whitespace and put error message
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            puts("\nError: Input incorrect\n");
        }

    }while(valid!=1);

    do{
        puts("What is the destination of this packet?\nEnter a numerical value between 1 & 1024");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].destination) == 1 //If decimal entry is detected and is between values 1 & 1024 copy int into memory
           && records[*rCount].destination >= 1
           && records[*rCount].destination <= 1024)
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            puts("Error: Input incorrect\n");
        }
    }while(valid!=1);

    do{
        puts("What is the packet type?\nEnter a numerical value between 0 & 10");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].type) == 1 //If decimal entry is detected and is ebtween values 0 & 10 copy int into memory
           && records[*rCount].type >= 0
           && records[*rCount].type <= 10)
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            puts("Error: Input incorrect\n");
        }
    }while(valid!=1);

    do{
        puts("What is the packet's port?\nEnter a numerical value between 1 & 1024");
        if(scanf("%d", &records[*rCount].port) == 1 //If decimal entry is detected and is between values 1 & 1024 copy int into memory
           && records[*rCount].port >= 1
           && records[*rCount].port <= 1024)
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            puts("Error: Input incorrect\n");
        }
    }while(valid!=1);

    do {
        puts("Enter up to 50 numerical characters");
        puts("\n**************Warning!**************\nEntering over 50 numerical characters will\ndelete anything after the first 50 characters");
    if (scanf(" %50[0-9]", records[*rCount].data) != 1)
            {
            valid = 0;
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            puts("Error: Input incorrect\n");

            }else
    {
        valid = 1;
        getchar();
        *rCount = *rCount+1;
    }
    }while(valid != 1);

       records = realloc(records,(*rCount+1)*sizeof(struct packet)); //reallocate memory to allow a new entry if needed
       return records;

}
```

This is my save to file function

```
void save(int rCount, struct packet *records){
      FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
      char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
      int i;

      puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
      scanf("%s", fileName);
      printf("\n%i Record(s) have been added to the file", rCount);
      printf("\nPress a key to continue");

      getch();                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                        //here in your program

      //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
      if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
          printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
          exit(1);
      }
      else{ //the file opened so print the records array of Person's to it
          for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
              fprintf(recordFile,"%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%s\n",records[i].source,records[i].destination,records[i].type,records[i].port,records[i].data);
          }
          fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
      }



}
```

Comment: `addRecord` return type is `struct packet*`? and return value use?

Comment: the return is to store it in memory, so I can call it back at a later point.

Comment: `addRecord(int *rCount, struct packet *records){` return type nothing is int.

Comment: I dont fully understand, can you expand. Thanks

Comment: Can not be confirmed in this code fragment.

Comment: You're not giving a clear full answer, this is making it very difficult to understand your answer.

Comment: BLUEPIXY's first comment was pointing out that the return type of addRecord appears to be absent, and would therefore default to int. However, what's actually occurred is that you have made an error in copying your function and so the return type (`struct packet *`) is included in the comment on the previous line.

Comment: is it possible to edit the code and show me what you mean, sorry it's really late and I've been doing code all day!
Thanks

**Edit, I undestand now, I'll edit this. thanks